# Is there a way that my android application can find out wether it is in ALPHA, BETA or LIVE?

Tags: android, google-play

We are now using the google play's staged roll-out functionality, but i would like the ALPHA release to point at a different server to BETA and LIVE. this will allow us to also stage releases the back end server code.

The problem is i can't see any way, within the android code, to check whether the app is in ALPHA, BETA, or LIVE.

Dose anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the Google Play capabilities to publish app in alpha/beta version?

Comment: AFAIK there's no API to do it. The most straight forward workaround is having the app telling your server the version number they're in and your server replies with the ALPHA-BETA-LIVE info.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Seraphim: yes i am.